# Requesting GNU extensions but otherwise POSIX-conformant functions?

Tags: c, linux, posix, glibc, standards-compliance

Is there a way with feature test macros to have glibc expose GNU extensions (functions not specified in POSIX, and additional flag/argument macros for standard functions, like `MAP_ANONYMOUS`), but still prefer POSIX semantics whenever the POSIX and GNU definitions conflict? I'm thinking things like `basename`, `strerror_r`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific case of `basename()`, including `<libgen.h>` header gives you the XPG / POSIX definition.

`MAP_ANONYMOUS` isn't a GNU extension (`_GNU_SOURCE`), it's defined if either `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_SVID_SOURCE` is defined.

Comment: It's pretty frustrating, because there are some things (`MAP_ANONYMOUS` being the best example) that aren't in POSIX but exist universally and which you really need for writing many programs. But adding `_GNU_SOURCE` means all sorts of functions might break because the GNU folks (or rather Ulrich Drepper) decide their way is better than the standard... Perhaps there's some other macro like `_BSD_SOURCE` that would get all the important stuff...

Comment: @R.: Yes, `_GNU_SOURCE` is *not* included by a default invocation of gcc, and is only required for things that are protected by `__USE_GNU` - a default invocation of gcc gives you `_BSD_SOURCE`, `_SVID_SOURCE`, `_POSIX_SOURCE` and `_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L`, which brings in pretty much everything you usually need.

Comment: The problem is that a portable program can't very well rely on the default environment being "mostly POSIX, plus some extras". On some systems, default is horribly non-conformant and `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=...` really is needed. Also it's common to want POSIX 2008/XOPEN 7, which for some reason aren't in the default yet...

Comment: Unfortunately, `_GNU_SOURCE` gets you a completely different version of `strerror_r`, too.

Comment: @R.: Sure, but you can explicitly ask for those definitions which are the defaults (though probably with a later `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` version).  I was just pointing out that `_GNU_SOURCE` isn't really needed for anything important, since it's not even included in the defaults.

Comment: @R.: If it is, it must be a recent change - my version doesn't ever define `_GNU_SOURCE` by itself, it relies on it being defined externally.  I think the point stands that you will get all the really useful things with just BSD, SYSV and POSIX.

Comment: It might not define `_GNU_SOURCE` (I'd need to check that again) but it still defines the `__USE` macros (honored by other headers) as if `_GNU_SOURCE` had been defined...

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because `_SVID_SOURCE` and `_BSD_SOURCE` in addition to the POSIX/XSI standard macros seem to be the closest thing to a solution for most of the desirable features (like `MAP_ANONYMOUS`).